# Changing anchor's href using jQuery AJAX, but HTML says href="undefined"

Tags: jquery, undefined, href

I've got an anchor element with `id="popup"`. When the page loads, it has `href="path/to/image.jpg"`.

I use AJAX to get the value to which I want to change the `href` of this anchor.

When I get the AJAX response, I do:

```
alert(jQuery("#popup").attr("href"));//alert 1
jQuery("#popup").attr("href", xhRequest.responseText);
alert(jQuery("#popup").attr("href"));//alert 2
```

(the `xhRequest.responseText` contains the correct value, but I get the same problem even if I just use a string literal).

The problem is that after I do this, the generated HTML in the page shows `href="undefined"` in the anchor element.

- Alert 1 correctly shows the initial value of the href attribute
- Alert 2 correctly shows the new value as the href
- The page itself shows `href="undefined"`

So the href is being effected somehow, but the value isn't being added properly.

**Updated**
For some reason the correct data is being returned, but only like this:

```
error: function(xhRequest, ErrorText, thrownError) {
    alert(xhRequest.status + ' ----' + xhRequest.responseText + '---');
    if ((xhRequest.responseText != '') && (document.getElementById("popup"))) {
        alert(jQuery("#popup").attr("href"));
        jQuery("#popup").attr("href", xhRequest.responseText);
        alert(jQuery("#popup").attr("href"));
    }
}​
```

The value of `xhRequest.status` is `200` and the value of `xhRequest.responseText` is `images/linked/ColorBeige.jpg`, as expected, with no spaces.

Comment: Where and when do you change the href?

Comment: does the first alert show the correct path? i.e. path/to/image.jpg

Comment: can you show your ajax code? are you using responseText before the response is available?

Comment: There might be empty spaces in the href.. Check that first..

How does xhRequest.responseText look like ??

Are you changing the href in the success callback of your request..

Comment: Even with empty spaces it works here using a string literal just fine: http://jsfiddle.net/FranWahl/48Sug/ If alert 2 is showing you the expected value and as you said, even using a string literal gives you the same issue, then this may look like something else is updating the anchor afterwords. Check your other code to make sure.

Comment: For some reason the correct data is being returned, but only like this: error:function (xhRequest, ErrorText, thrownError){
 alert(xhRequest.status + ' ----' + xhRequest.responseText + '---');
  if((xhRequest.responseText !='')&&(document.getElementById("popup"))){
          alert(jQuery("#popup").attr("href"));
          jQuery("#popup").attr("href", xhRequest.responseText);
      alert(jQuery("#popup").attr("href"));
         }
        }  the value of xhRequest.status is 200 and the value of xhRequest.responseText is images/linked/ColorBeige.jpg, as expected, with no spaces.

Comment: It appears Francois had the correct explanation. Commenting out all the AJAX stuff, it appears that I have inherited a clusterf*ck and something else is changing the href to 'undefined'.

You guys are all great, thanks so much and sorry if you think this was a bit of a waste of time for you.